# C++ How to parse JSON response using cppRest Library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to parse JSON response using cppRest Library, but an exception is raised instead the JSON object, here is the error that is show below:

```
Incorrect Content-Type: must be textual to extract_string, JSON to extract_json.
```

And here is my code that I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace web;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    uri url(L"http://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0");
    
    http_client client(url);
    http_response response;
    http_request req;

    req.set_method(methods::GET);
    req.headers().set_content_type(L"application/json");
    response = client.request(req).get();
    try
    {
        json::object json_object(response.extract_json().get().as_object());
    }
    catch (exception &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check network traffic to see the actual response you're getting from the server. The problem is with the response you're getting. Without being familiar with this HTTP client library: the `set_content_type` call looks wrong. Your apparent intent is to indicate to the server that you want `application/json`, and this method sounds like it's setting `Content-Type:`. This is wrong. In an HTTP request the appropriate header for that is `Accept:` and not `Content-Type:`. See RFC 2616 for more information.

Comment: the server isn't correctly setting the content type, its incorrectly set to `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, presumably setting `ignore_content_type` will fix your problem: https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1http__response.html#a2de616fedbe4b50ce5a67bce00675968

Comment: The error is no more, but I could not get the JSON Object

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, looks like I need to set the response headers to get the received content type as json:

**Updated my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace web;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    uri url(L"http://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0");
    
    http_client client(url);
    http_request req;

    req.set_method(methods::GET);
    pplx::task<json::value> requestTask = client.request(req).then([](http_response response)
    {
    
        json::value jsonObject;
        try
        {

            if ( response.status_code() == status_codes::OK )
            {
                response.headers().set_content_type(L"application/json"); // Set headers to receive content type as JSON 
                jsonObject = response.extract_json().get();
            }
        }
        catch (const http_exception& e)
        {
            cout << e.error_code().message() << "\n";
        }
        
        return jsonObject; // returned a json value
    
    });

    json::array dataseries = requestTask.get().at(L"dataseries").as_array(); // We get the returned response here

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataseries.size(); i++)
    {
        auto timepoint = dataseries[i].at(L"timepoint");
        wcout << timepoint << endl;
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```